# Can a Q&A be too minor?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I tried a bit and finally found out how to set the + and - key for zoom in Notepad++ with a German keyboard layout*. I thought about writing my first Q&A here, but it might be a too small question for this. Does it matter if the question is very minor?

This question seems to imply yes, but I'm not sure. It's more about when the answer is somewhere else already: *[Are some questions too easy for Super User?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/1445/681763)*

<sub>* Basically choose <kbd>=</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> instead of <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd>, but not what a picture of an English keyboard layout would make you think, <kbd>\</kbd> and <kbd>/</kbd>.</sub>

Comment: Answering a minor question that makes life easier for a lot of novice users probably provides more benefit than answering an advanced question of use to only a couple of users.

Comment: But both are equally welcomed and encouraged. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my understanding, that other meta question means that you should first do some research on your problem (e.g. a Google search) before asking a question. If you can't find the answer after some searching, then it's perfectly fine to ask a question here. In fact, very specific/focused questions, expressed clearly, are good things. It's trivial/obvious questions that may be discouraged.

Therefore, I encourage you to post your question. Make sure to include any relevant things you've found from your research and any special circumstances of your setup.

Comment: What I did now is making it more general by trying out all other keys and making a complete list of what the key list in N++ means for a German keyboard. While typing the question and answer it felt kind of weird being so specific. And I think this way it helps more people and prevents other Q&As like "How to set # key", "How to set ^ key", etc. If there's something to improve my Q&A, please tell me (or do it), because, as I said, it's my first.